# Sorting from 2nd query OR functioning join query

Tags: php, sorting, join, pdo

i currently have a table i need displayed like this:
[image: result]

but as you can see, its not sorted on "amount dropped" (named $amount and amount in the code)
i first need to gather the names and drop_id's from a table. which is done like this:

```
//----------------FETCH ALL CONTENTS FROM DROPTABLE TO DISPLAY DROPS------------\\

$query = "SELECT * FROM droptable
WHERE boss_id = ". $boss ."";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row){
    $drop_id = $row['drop_id'];
    $drop = $row['dropname'];
    $boss_id = $row['boss_id'];

    $picture = $row['picture'];
```

this fetches the name of the drop(dropname). the id for it (drop_id), the boss id (boss_id) and the picture for it (picture).
it then goes on to check if ive ever logged a drop from the boss from another table:

```
//----------------FETCH ALL LOGGED DROPS FOR DISPLAYING AMOUNT------------\\
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM dropcounter
        WHERE boss_id = ". $boss ." AND userid = ". $user ." AND drop_id = ". $drop_id ."";

        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><img src='../images/". $picture ."'</td>";
          echo "<td>". $drop . "</td>";
          echo "<td>". $amount ."</td>";    
          echo "<td>". $percent ."</td>";
          echo "<form action='logger.php' method='post'>";
          echo "<td><input type='hidden' value=". $drop_id ." name='drop_id'>";
          echo "<input type='hidden' value=". $boss_id ." name='boss_id'>";
          echo "<input type='hidden' value=". $user ." name='user'>";
          echo "<input type='submit' value='Add'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
```

this does everything i want exept sort on amount dropped or drop percentage (since they will sort the same). ive tried adding "ORDER BY amount DESC" in the 2nd query but it didnt sort.

ive also tried using JOIN, but it didnt come close to the result i wanted and i got stuck for 3 days on the query so went with the above code instead. but im willing to use join again if my wished result can be done.

here's the JOIN code that doesnt work:

```
$query = "SELECT dropcounter.drop_id, dropcounter.boss_id, dropcounter.add_date, dropcounter.username, dropcounter.amount, droptable.drop_id, droptable.dropname, droptable.boss_id, droptable.wiki_link, droptable.picture
FROM droptable
JOIN dropcounter
ON droptable.boss_id = dropcounter.boss_id
WHERE dropcounter.drop_id = droptable.drop_id AND droptable.boss_id = ". $boss ." AND dropcounter.username = ". $user ."
ORDER BY dropcounter.amount";
```

here's the structure i have on my tables:
DROPCOUNTER TABLE:

[image: dropcounter table]

and here's DROPTABLE table:

[image: droptable table]

if anyone would be able to help me with either one if them i would be very glad for your kindness!

here's a fiddle if anyone wanna try it out. ive imported some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d66846/1/0

Comment: Your second code doesn't do anything with `$result1`.

Comment: I think the join should work. Can you add the `dropcounter` table contents? Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: @Barmar the second code does do something with it. but i didnt include it as it is only assigning everything to variables. and what is sqlfiddle? and ive added the contents of dropcounter

Comment: sqlfiddle is sqlfiddle.com, a public web site that lets you create SQL samples and share them with others.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d66846/1/0 there's some sample data to play with

Comment: I tried your join here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d66846/3 it looks like it works. What's wrong with the result?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06edc/2/0 here's a better example. now it has a value that isnt registered as an entry in dropcounter. and i need it to appear as a 0 in the list. or this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06edc/1/0

Comment: Then user `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get rows from `droptable` that don't have a match in `dropcounter`. All the tests that refer to `dropcounter` have to be in the `ON` clause, otherwise the null matches will cause the tests to fail and those rows will be filtered out.

```
SELECT dc.add_date, dc.username, IFNULL(dc.amount, 0) amount, dt.drop_id, dt.dropname, dt.boss_id, dt.wiki_link, dt.picture
FROM droptable dt
LEFT JOIN dropcounter dc
ON dt.boss_id = dc.boss_id AND dc.drop_id = dt.drop_id AND dc.userid = $user
WHERE dt.boss_id = $boss
ORDER BY amount
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06edc/8)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use in joined statement:

```
dropcounter.username = ". $user ."
```

which contains 2 errors:
1. there isn't field username in that table
2. you haven't enclosed string in ''

Change it to `dropcounter.userid`

Also you don't need to select droptable.drop_id and droptable.boss_id as it's already selected from dropcounter table.

EDIT: Based on your fiddle:

```
SELECT dropcounter.drop_id, dropcounter.boss_id, dropcounter.userid, dropcounter.amount,    droptable.dropname
FROM droptable
JOIN dropcounter
ON droptable.boss_id = dropcounter.boss_id
WHERE dropcounter.drop_id = droptable.drop_id AND droptable.boss_id = 1 AND dropcounter.userid = 1
ORDER BY dropcounter.amount DESC;
```

It works and sorts without problem.

Comment: ive changed the table since. username is now userid. and its enclosed? ". $user ." <- isnt that enclosed?

Comment: username suggested that it's VARCHAR field and you need enclose values for that type in ' '. what exactly means "here's the JOIN code that doesnt work:"?

Comment: yeah. the join statement. that code doesnt work. it doesnt give me the result i wanted for 3 days so i stopped updating it

Comment: Edited answer and added JOINED SELECT based on your fiddle.